# Best Hand Saw for Cutting Hardboard?

Tags: wood, saw

I have read a few websites searching for the answer. The answers go on and on without really clearly answering the question. I know a power tool is best. I know low angle. I know cut on the push, not the pull. What I need is a good saw. Please.

What hand saw is best to use for cutting hardboard?

Thank you

Comment: Opinion based and seems a shopping question; voting to close. Define best. Cleanest cut? Fastest cut? Can handle curves or cutouts? Personally, I love my fine tooth pull saw for thin materials, but it doesn't do curves very well and isn't the fastest hand saw. If I could only have one manual saw, that would be it; it's small, sharp, and has great control.

Comment: A sharp one.  Any other type will need to know the type of cuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any **sharp** one suited for the cut you want.

So a coping saw if you need to cut little curves, a straight saw if you're looking for straight line cuts, and fine tooth would be good considering the typical thickness of the stuff.

A pull saw (typically "Japanese style" in the US market, anyway) is just fine (it's the same as a "push" from the other side - there's no fundamental difference other than how you use it.)

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the clear answer.

Comment: Pull saws have advantages for certain kinds of straight line cuts if you need a very thin kerf, since the blade can be thinner. Other than that... Hardboard has no grain, so it's neither a crosscut nor a rip. Power tools are _not_ inherently better unless you are making many cuts, and then the type of cut determines which has advantages or disadvantages.

Comment: The best tool is the one you are mist comfortable with, that you have available, for that specific task. It is possible to do fine carving with a hatchet, and sone people foo, but it isn't the tool I'd reach for first for that job.

Comment: Remember too that the goal of mist took reviews is to get you to spend money on tools. I'm as guilty as anyone of buying more toys than I need, but ...